# What is the best method to deploy/clone contracts in a Factory contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I made a factory contract but can't figure out what would be the best method to use in the createContract function:

```
function createContract(uint256 x, uint256 y) external returns (address contractAddress) {
        MyContract contract = new MyContract(x, y);
        contractAddress = address(contract);
}
```

OR would this method be better:

```
function createContract(uint256 x, uint256 y) external returns (address contractAddress) {
        bytes memory bytecode = type(MyContract).creationCode;
        bytecode = abi.encodePacked(bytecode, abi.encode(x, y));
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(x, y));
        assembly {
            contractAddress := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
}
```

Which one would be more gas efficient, have less time complexity and less code size?

Answer (score 2):

The first approach uses the original `create` opcode while the second approach uses the [create2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) opcode.

Since your goal is lower gas price, the first snippet is more useful for your case.

Specifically, with `MyContract` accepting 2 `uint256` params in the constructor, being otherwise empty, and without compiler optimization, here's the transaction costs:

- 1st snippet: 67,720 gas
- 2nd snippet: 69,789 gas

If your goal was a deterministic address of `MyContract` based on values of `x` and `y`, then the second approach would be suitable, since the first one doesn't allow it.